# Sorting an array of structs (Cards)

Tags: c++, sorting, struct, overloading

I am making a blackjack game and have created an array to act as the hand the user is dealt. I want to be able to sort it so that the hand is sorted in numerical order so it will be simpler to determine what type of hand the user has. Here is my sturct for the cards:

```
struct ACard{
    int num;
    const char *pic;
};
```

I want to sort the array by `int num`. I have tried to just use a simple insertion sort to complete the sort but I believe I need overload the operator to do so but I'm having trouble doing so as I've never overloaded a struct like this before. Here is what I have for the sort so far:

```
        int i,j;
        ACard key;
        for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
            key = userHand[i].num;
            j = i - 1;

            while(j >= 0 && userHand[j].num > key){
                userHand[j + 1] = userHand[j];
                j = j - 1;
            }
            userHand[j + 1] = key;
        }
```

*Note `userHand` is the array of `ACard's` that I wish to sort.

Comment: Is there a reason why you won't use `std::array` or `std::vector` to store the ACards and just use `std::sort()` with a custom comparator?

Comment: Why don't you use `std::sort` with a comparison lambda?

Comment: Im not familiar with the std::sort (), could you explain?

Comment: [Documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

Comment: I was able to figure how to write my own  compare function to sort, thanks for the insight

Answer (score 2):

With STL containers you can use `std::sort` function. First two arguments define the range of elements to be sorted. Third argument defines a `LessThan` function used for your custom elements comparison (you can use lambda expression for that).

```
std::vector<ACard> userHand; // or another stl container

// initialize userHand somehow

std::sort(userHand.begin(), userHand.end(),
    [](const ACard& left, const ACard& right)
    {
        return left.num < right.num;
    });
```

Comment: Right idea. Looks like the right code. But lacking in explanation of what you've done. You won't need much since this code is damn near self documenting.